# Facebook pop up not scrollable in WebView - React native

Tags: iphone, react-native, facebook, webview

My app has a WebView and works fine in Android and iOS, although in some cases the following Facebook pop up asking for cookies is shown and it's not possible to scroll down. Then the whole web view is not usable.

[image]

The code is very simple:

```
<WebView
  source={{
    uri: url
  }}/>
```

How could I make it scrollable as well?
Thanks!

Comment: Is it happening with the Facebook URL or nothing is scrollable in `webview`?

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan With my Android and iOS simulator is all good even if the pop up appears because it fits completely in the screen. When I try with my mobile phone the pop up appears but too big and it needs to scroll, but I can't. I would like to make it always scrollable

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution could be to include the webview inside a ScrollView

```
<ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1 }}>
  <WebView
    source={{
      uri: url
    }}/>
</ScrollView>
```

Other possible solution could be using:

https://github.com/iou90/react-native-autoheight-webview#readme

Note: if the webview is already included in a `ScrollView` check if setting some `bottomPadding` or some `contentInset` makes the modal scrollable till the end.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution is too small to show the entire popup.

You can either zoom out with something like:

```
webview.setInitialScale(1);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true); 
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
```

Or you can [edit the web page itself](https://medium.com/@skywall/inject-js-into-androids-webview-8845fb5902b7) to scale down using the page's viewport meta, shrink the popup with CSS, or add a scrollbar to that specific element by setting the css of the element to:

```
#target{
max-height:100%;
overflow:scroll;
}
```